Angular 12 to 13 upgrade issue
I'm trying to upgrade Angular 12 to 13. But in the end, I'd like to upgrade to v16, just fyi.
First of all, I upgraded angular/cli, core, ngx-build-plus, material, typescript, etc for angular 13.
In my angular.json, I have this.
"architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "ngx-build-plus:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/v2",
            "index": "",
            "main": "projects/c-component/src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "projects/c-component/src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/c-component/tsconfig.lib.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "projects/c-component/src/assets",
            
            ],
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "node_modules/"
              ]
            },
            "scripts": [
              {
                "bundleName": "polyfill-webcomp-es5",
                "input": "node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/custom-elements-es5-adapter.js"
              },
              {
                "bundleName": "polyfill-webcomp",
                "input": "node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/bundles/webcomponents-sd-ce-pf.js"
              },
              "node_modules/rxjs/bundles/rxjs.umd.js",
              "node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js",
              "node_modules/@angular/animations/bundles/animations.umd.js",
              "node_modules/@angular/material/bundles/material.umd.js",
              "node_modules/@angular/cdk/bundles/cdk.umd.js",
              "node_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js",
              "node_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common-http.umd.js",
              "node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js",
              "node_modules/@angular/elements/bundles/elements.umd.js",
              "node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js",
              "node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js"
            ]
          },

in scripts part[] above, rxjs and @angular umd js files are included in scripts. But after upgrading to v13, those umd js files are not there anymore in node_modules. Instead, there are mjs files in for example, under fesm2020 or fesm2015.
so, I replaced the above js files with mjs files. and ran the application.
and getting this error and nothing worked
Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
[1] Error: Transform failed with 1 error:
[1] C:/dev/frontend/test/projects/chat-showcase/src/app/app.component.scss:17:100: ERROR: Unterminated string token
[1]     at C:\dev\frontend\test\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\loader.js:81:18
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
[1]
[1] ./projects/chat-showcase/src/polyfills.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
[1] Error: Transform failed with 1 error:
[1] C:/dev/frontend/test/projects/chat-showcase/src/app/app.component.scss:17:100: ERROR: Unterminated string token
[1]     at C:\dev\frontend\test\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\loader.js:81:18
[1]     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)

Could anyone give me some idea how to resolve this?
Thanks in advance
Tried to run the application and make a build

Updating libraries or frameworks can be complicated.the backend team took a month to upgrade node on múltiples repos.
I would delete package-lock.json, delete node_modules and then install the new angular versión, then npm install and try to start the app and look for errors, sometimes the IDE helps to fix them, sometimes You have to refactor some code but You never know until You try to start the app
